# Payment method should be active based on country magento2

Tags: magento2

I want to set payment method based on country in Magento2 . I am having two payment method, one for international and other for local. So, based on the country , payment methods should be active.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Payment Methods ->
- Set "Payment for Applicable Countries" to "Specific Countries"
- Select countries in "Payment from Specific Countries"

[image]